# activate click feature on button created after click of previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

I am creating an application in which there is a button in a webpage.class = "button"

after clicking the button another button is created of same class.Now I want the same function is applied on the newly created button on click. But its not happening.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var temp = '<input type="button" class="button" />'
$('#form').append(temp);
})
```

This function is working for the first button which is created on page load.But this is not working on the button which is created after clicking of the previous button.
How to fix this issue? 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because events are attached on load of the DOM. Therefore any elements added after that point do not have the event. The fix is to use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$('#form').on('click', '.button', function(){
    var temp = '<input type="button" class="button" />'
    $('#form').append(temp);
})
```

Comment: actually this code is working after after form click.But If I change it to .button click then its not working .. I need the furntion on button click